# half of the contentof appears on next page in print privew of html page

Tags: html, css

I was able to show my web page on print privew dialog using media tags
For which I have build up a seprate css.

Now  half of my table content appears on first page and the remaing part comes on second.Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post some more information? Maybe a screenshot of the distorted print-preview?

Comment: stackoverflow: u need 10 reputation to post an image....

Comment: Yeah, this sucks. But you could still upload it somewhere else and provide a link

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zoom` in your css to reduce the page size:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom

```
html{
    zoom: 50%;
}
```

Another option would be to use tranform: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale

```
html{
    transform:  scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

Note that you might need vendor-specific prefixes (`-moz-`, ...)

Comment: here only page gets adjusted not the content..so issue still persist.